# How to remove Flurry ad banner from view

Tags: ios, flurry

I am using Flurry in my iOS app, to display banner ads as follows:

```
self.flurryBanner = [[FlurryAdBanner alloc] initWithSpace:@"FlurryBanner"];
self.flurryBanner.adDelegate = self;

[self.flurryBanner fetchAdForFrame:self.view.frame];
```

while I can find documentation in AdMob to hide banner (setHidden = YES), I could not find any information on how to do so. Any ideas for a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

UIView *flurryContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

[self.view addSubview:flurryContainer];

[self.flurryBanner displayAdInView:flurryContainer viewControllerForPresentation:self];

And then flurryContainer.hidden = YES;